# RotationModifier revert sprite to initial value. how to avoid it?

Tags: android, rotation, andengine

I'm trying to rotate sprite of certain angle and keep it in that way. I simply call sprite.registerEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(5,0,180))
This rotates sprite and reverts it to initial (0) angle after finish.
I was also trying to call sprite.setRotation() in onModifierFinish() method, it didn't helped.

Anyway - what is the proper way to rotate sprite / keep effects of modifier after it finish?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I was unnecesarry attaching physics to this sprite. Sprite without physics rotates as i wanted and stays it this way